# UML Activity Diagram - join

Tags: uml, diagram, activity-diagram

i have following Activity Diagram:

[image]

I need to solve the upper section of diagram.

The "false" branches of decision and their join before getting to "Show form" action, it my solution ok or should this be solved some other way ( all three arrows to the show form or some diamond join) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One glaring problem is that “Show Form” deadlocks. It can never start because *all* tokens must arrive on all arrows before it can start. The way an activity diagram works is that each action is a step. A completed action offers tokens to outgoing edges. As soon as any action is offered all the tokens it needs to start, it actually starts. I recommend you read the [excellent series by Conrad Bock](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_07/column3/) to be sure you understand how activities work.

Comment: It should be mentioned that it's not a Join (hor./ver. bar) but a Merge nodes (diamond) which is missing.

Comment: Also, my opinion, one can live with the OP's diagram as it can be understood by humans although it's syntactically wrong. Anyone _knows_ how it's meant. So if there's no machine, the notation can be documented along with the model in the specific domain.

Comment: Why use UML at all if you’re going to ignore the meaning of the symbols? My hope is that the OP will read more than a quick fix. “Quick! Fix my symbols to make me a mathematician!”

Comment: Ah no. There is not always the need to have an exact model. Except you model the next Mars rocket. Respect your domain. Some want it more quick. Some more exact. Euclide was right, though.

Comment: Then don’t mess about with UML, use Visio or something informal.

Comment: Languages live. UML is a language. And you can introduce dialects. Some dialects are only understood in certain domains. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It appears we are not going to convince each other, and this is not the right forum to do so.